# No jetty:run variable in arguments to debug with Maven Jetty Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, jetty

I am following [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+with+the+Maven+Jetty+Plugin+inside+Eclipse) to debug my webapp with Maven Jetty,

I 've been able to `mvn jetty:run` and it successfully ran my application on Maven Jetty.

but when I try to configure Eclipse to debug with Jetty, there is no jetty:run variable on "Arguments".

Why could this be?

I am setting the location of maven to my apache-maven-3.0.4 directory. Mave is should be pointing to the eclipse plugin? Which I don't even know where it is...

Answer (score 0):

It is so obvious that is shameful.

Don't know if it was meant to be on Arguments and why it was not, but I just typed it in as it is and it worked.